# Duplicate form submition through $("#formname").submit();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, duplicates, submission

I have a line of HTML drop down lists, and whenever the user selects one of the options, it calls a jQuery function through a class which submits the form.

```
<form id="workorderform" action="saveworkorder.php" method="post">
    <select name="applicationtype" class="checkvalueonchange savevalueonchange">
         <option></option>
         <option value="Uplift" <?php echo ($wo['applicationtype']=='Uplift')?'selected':''; ?>>Uplift</option>
     </select> 
 </form>
```

the `savevalueonchange` class calls

```
$(".savevalueonchange").change(function() {
    autoSave(); 
});
```

which then calls

```
function autoSave() {
    if($("#wostatus").val()=='open'){
         $("#workorderform").submit();
    }
 }
```

which posts the information to the `saveworkorder.php`

```
//remove existing chargecodes
$sql = "DELETE FROM workorderchargecodes WHERE compresscoid = '".trim($_REQUEST['formid'])."'";
mssql_query($sql, $dbconn);
//now save chargecodes  
$code_prefix = 'code_';
foreach($_POST as $thisPostKey => $thisPostValue) {
    if((substr($thisPostKey, 0, strlen($code_prefix)))==$code_prefix) {
        if(trim($thisPostValue)!=''):
             $exists=false;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM workorderchargecodes WHERE compresscoid='".trim($_REQUEST['formid'])."' AND code='".substr($thisPostKey, strlen($code_prefix), strlen($thisPostKey))."'";
            $res = mssql_query($sql, $dbconn);
            while($arr = mssql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                $exists=true;
            } 
            if($exists==false){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO workorderchargecodes (
                    compresscoid,
                    code,
                    time
                    ) VALUES (
                    '".trim($_REQUEST['formid'])."',
                    '".substr($thisPostKey, strlen($code_prefix), strlen($thisPostKey))."',                         '".$thisPostValue."'
            )";
                mssql_query($sql, $dbconn);
            }   
        endif;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am selecting the code from the database before I insert it into the database and am somehow still getting duplicate charge codes. I have messed with this for a few months now, and it still keeps happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: give the db field a unique index, problem solved.

Comment: `var_dump($exists)` before you do your insert to see if your logic is working.

Comment: Are you saying that it's posting twice or are you refering to your SQL Code? Is the class ".checkvalueonchange" doing any javaScript function? Also, if you run jQuery(".savevalueonchange").data("events") how many events are hooked up?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `return false;` in your **autosave()**, like this :

```
function autoSave() {

   if($("#wostatus").val()=='open'){

       $("#workorderform").submit();

       return false;  // add here
   }
}
```

It will prevent to submit twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="workorderform" action="saveworkorder.php" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <select name="applicationtype" class="checkvalueonchange savevalueonchange">
         <option></option>
         <option value="Uplift" <?php echo ($wo['applicationtype']=='Uplift')?'selected':''; ?>>Uplift</option>
     </select> 
 </form>
```

use this form

it use `obsubmit="return false;"`